# Using parent() to get values in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

I'm printing the below HTML piece in a loop.

```
<div class = "commentbox">
    <input type="hidden" name="postid" value="${p.postid}" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="username"  value="${username}" /> 
        <input type="hidden" name="source" value="user_home" />
    <textarea name="comment" cols="40" rows="1" class="add_comment"
        placeholder="Add a comment..."></textarea>
    <div class="post_con">
        <button type="submit" class="postcomment">Post</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have this jQuery piece where I would like to get the `<input name="postid">` value when clicking on the `<button class="postcomment">`.

```
$(".postcomment").click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    var postid = parent.find(".postid").val();
    console.log(postid);
});
```

However, it logs `undefined`. How can I get the `postid` value?

Comment: I dont see postid class. Do you mean reviewid?

Comment: @Evus hey! Made a mistake. Check it out again.

Comment: I know this is answered, but your jq would have worked if you stepped up one more parent... `var parent = $(this).parent().parent();` The `postcomment` is inside a div (parent1) then that is inside another div - `commentbox` (parent2). -- You were trying to `find()` in the `post_con` div...  `closest()` is better anyway :)

Comment: @Scott thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up to `commentbox` element which is common parent of both element `postcomment` and `postid` elements.

Then as you have specified `postid` in `name` attribute you can use [`Attribute value selector`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

```
$(".postcomment").click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).closest('.commentbox');
    var postid = parent.find("[name=postid]").val();
    console.log(postid);
});
```

Comment: Wow! That was straightforward. Thanks for the quick help